# lockScaling for Fabric.js objects

Tags: fabricjs

I'm not sure if I misunderstood something about the API or if this is a real bug, so I'm asking here before I open an issue.

I'm drawing a few objects on a Canvas and I don't want to be able to do any manipulations (move, rotate, scale) on them except for the selection itself. Indeed, when I select a single object I can't do anything with it. However, when I select a group of objects, I can't move or rotate them, but dragging the corners of the selection ***does*** in fact scale the objects.

I'm using Fabric.js 1.3.0 on Windows 7. Tried this on Chrome, Firefox and IE10 and the behavior was the same on all three.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/fabricjs-1.3.0/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

            canvas.setWidth(150);
            canvas.setHeight(150);

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                for (var j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
                        top: 20+i * 20, left: 20+j * 20, width: 10, height: 10, fill: 'blue',
                        selectable: true,
                        lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true,
                        hasControls: false,
                        lockScaling: true, lockRotation: true
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:
I found a suggestion if [Fabric's google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/0T4wpNz_QBc) to register on the scale event:

```
canvas.onBeforeScaleRotate = function lock(object) { 
    object.lockScaling = true; 
}
```

But this didn't help. Also, even if it did help, this is very unintuitive. What is the difference between lockMovement and lockScaling? The lockMovement configuration works, whereas the lockScaling configuration doesn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `lockScaling` property.
You have to use `lockScalingX` and `lockScalingY`

See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#lockScalingX

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I fill kind of stupid. Though in my defense, the tutorial mentions nothing about the existance of two different properties: "Every object on canvas can be locked in few ways. "lockMovementX", "lockMovementY", "lockRotation", "lockScaling" are properties that lock corresponding object actions. So setting object.lockMovementX to true prevents object from being moved horizontally. You can still move it in vertical plane though. Simiarly, lockRotation prevents rotation and lockScaling — scaling." Maybe you could update the tutorial...

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Your right, we have to update the tutorials.